# Grails 2.3.11 Error compiling "org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core"

Tags: grails

I am updating an old code, but I am still in the phase of resolving the dependencies, I have the following configuration in my BuildConfig.grovy:

```
plugins {
compile group: 'org.gagravarr', name: 'vorbis-java-core', version: '0.8'
}
```

But at the moment that I try to generate the prod war is presenting me the error below, saying that can not do the download of the dependencies, someone knows how to configure the repository for this plugin? Or have the source code of this plugin and give me a hint how to put it to get the plugin saved and instead of downloading?

```
| Error Failed to resolve dependencies (Set log level to 'warn' in BuildConfig.g
roovy for more information):

- org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core:0.8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add an entry to the plugins section, it has to be a real [grails 2.x plugin](https://grails.org/plugins).

`org.gagravarr:vorbis-java-core:0.8` seems to be a regular dependency.
Try to add it to the dependencies section:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.gagravarr', name: 'vorbis-java-core', version: '0.8'
}
```